# gnus-article-mode-hook does not fire when opening an article in Gnus

Tags: gnus

I want to highlight keywords when I open an email (article) in Gnus. This is what I have so far.

```
(add-hook 'gnus-article-mode-hook (lambda() (highlight-phrase "\\(TODO\\|job\\|Mike\\)")))
```

I also tried this which did not work either.

```
gnus-article-prepare-hook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me on Emacs25. A better way to debug this is not to use the lambda:

```cl
(defun ora-gnus-article-hook ()
  (message "test"))
(add-hook 'gnus-article-mode-hook 'ora-gnus-article-hook)
```

Now you can instrument `ora-gnus-article-hook` with <kbd>C-u C-M-x</kbd> to see when it's getting called.  You can also continuously re-define `ora-gnus-article-hook` without having to update `gnus-article-mode-hook`.  In fact, once you put a lambda into a hook, the only way to remove it from that hook is basically `(setq gnus-article-mode-hook nil)`.

Comment: Great that worked, it was the lambda causing the issue. Side note the hook that worked best was `gnus-article-prepare-hook` .
Thanks